# Change the mailbox name when creating a new profile with ProfMan

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm using ProfMan to create an Outlook Profile with multiple exchange mailboxes.

[(example here)](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#ROH_Profile_Outlook2016)

Each mailbox is creating with a mailbox name of 'Microsoft Exchange' instead of the email address this makes it impossible to tell them apart in the Outlook 'send as' field.

I've been trying to find the correct ProfSect item to update but cant figure out which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account name is no longer stored in the MAPI profile session; Outlook uses `IOlkAccountManager`. After creating a new account, you can retrieve it from the `RDOSession.Accounts` collection and set the `RDOAccount.Name` property.

Keep in mind that if Outlook is running `IOlkAccountManager` won't see it until you call `RDOSession.Accounts.RefreshFromMAPI` (not yet publicly available - it will be in the upcoming version 6.5).